# Python: MemoryError in generating a array

Tags: python, numpy

I am using anaconda2 with python 2.7 in 64-bit wind10 with RAM of 4G. My codes are as follows:

```
number_of_documents = 21578
document_max_num_words = 100
num_features = 500
X = np.zeros(shape=(number_of_documents, document_max_num_words, num_features)).astype('float32')
```

In generating x, the memory error occurs.

Comment: But are you using a 64 bit build of Python?

Comment: Also Note, since you are using `astype` on the result of your call to `numpy.zeros`, it will first build an array of floats of your default float type, which may be `np.float64`, which will require about `1578*100*500*8*1e-9 == 8.6312` gigabytes of memory. It then must make a copy, so it will require those 8 gigs plus about 4 gigs for the copy. Use the `dtype` argument to `np.zeros` instead of `astype` if you have less than 8 gigs of memory.

Comment: What is the result of `import sys; print(sys.version)`?

Comment: @JohnLaRooy: I am suing Python 2.7.12 :: Anaconda 4.2.0 (64-bit)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: 2.7.12 |Anaconda 4.2.0 (64-bit)| (default, Jun 29 2016, 11:07:13) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]

Comment: OK, how much memory does your machine have?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: I will try putting astype inside

Comment: @jingweimo no, you don't put `astype` inside anything, you *use the `dtype`* parameter to `np.zeros`. But again, how much memory are you working with? Maybe you just don't have enough memory.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: the method does not work, still gives the memory error. My pc has RAM of 4G

Comment: @jingweimo well then, there is your issue. You don't have enough memory for an array with those dimensions and float32 data type, that requires `21578*100*500*4*1e-9 == 4.3156` gigabytes

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: You are right. I have tested the code on another computer with 8G RAM. It works fine

Answer (score 0):

You are just running out of memory, so what you can do is to use swap. Although using swap memory is much slower than using physical memory, it can work, isn't it?

See this link to check how to set swap memory.

[How to Add a Swap File On Ubuntu Linux](https://www.howtoforge.com/ubuntu-swap-file)